# OnTouch worked for 1 Button, but not for 3

Tags: android, button, crash, touch-event, ontouchlistener

im new with Android, but have experiance in c# and c++.

Im just trying to display whenever a button is pressed. I searched and found out, that the onClick event cant do that, therefore i use the onTouch-event.

For the first button it was fine and worked. Then I added a sencond and a third one, but now the application crashes, when I execute it.

If I delete the second and the third button with their events, the application still crashes. Not before I delete the first Button and his event the application stops crashing.

here the code of my main.code and the layout-xml:

```
package com.android.kurve;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    boolean left=false;
    boolean right=false;

    final Button buttonLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button buttonRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button buttonMove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        buttonLeft.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                      left=true;
                      text.setText("left");
                    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                      left=false;
                    }
                return true;
            }
        });
        buttonRight.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                      right=true;
                      text.setText("right");

                    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                      right=false;
                    }
                return true;
            }
        });

        buttonMove.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

              text.setText("move");

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

and here the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="207dp"
        android:text="Left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:text="Right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Move" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You must attach the LogCat exceptions.

Comment: ok thanks. i search what it is and hope that it will help me

Comment: it says: java.lang.runntimeexeption: unable to instanciate activity componentinfo java.lang.nullpointerexeption

Comment: thanks for the tip with the logcat exeption. i googled my error and found out, that im not allowed to assign my buttons outside of the onCreate-methode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem could be that you are initializing the layout element globally instead to initializing them in the "onCreate" method. This method is called when the activity is created, so this is the place where all the layout behaviour or values should be initialized.